# Are there unique geodesics in the NIL and SOL geometry?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Is there a unique geodesics between any two points in the [NIL (resp. SOL) geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture#Nil_geometry)?
If so, is there a nice way of parametrizing them? For example geodesics in $S^3$ can be parametrized using the embedding in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\sin , \cos$ functions. Geodesics in hyperbolic space can be parametrized using the [hyperboloid model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_space) and the functions sinh,cosh.

Comment: Look at [Kaplan, On the geometry of groups of Heisenberg type.
Bull. London Math. Soc. 15 (1983), no. 1, 35--42], as well as the papers referring to it in mathscinet. 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The geodesics between points are not unique in both cases. Moreover the following is true: if $M$ is a universal cover of a compact Riemannian manifold whose fundamental group is virtually solvable but not virtually abelian, then there are conjugate points on some geodesics in $M$ and hence geodesics between some points are not unique.

See Croke and Schroeder "[The fundamental group of compact manifolds without conjugate points](https://eudml.org/doc/140046)", Comment. Math. Helv.  61  (1986),  no. 1, 161--175, [MR847526](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=847526), for the case when the metric is analytic, and Lebedeva "On the fundamental group of a compact space without conjugate points", [here](ftp://ftp.pdmi.ras.ru/pub/publicat/preprint/2002/05-02.ps.gz), for the general case.

Answer (score 13):

There are not unique geodesics between points in Sol geometry. The Sol metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$ may be given as $e^{-z}dx^2+e^zdy^2+dz^2$. The claim is that there is not a unique geodesic between $(0,0,0)$ and $(t,t,0)$ for $t$ large enough.

There is a rotational isometry $(x,y,z)\overset{\varphi}{\mapsto}(y,x,-z)$. This leaves invariant the line $l=\{(t,t,0)|t\in \mathbb{R}\}$,
and therefore $l$ is a geodesic. For $t$ small enough, $(t,t,0)$ will lie in a normal coordinate patch about $(0,0,0)$, so $l$ will be the unique shortest geodesic between these points.

However, for $t$ large, there are much shorter paths connecting $(0,0,0)$ and $(t,t,0)$. The length of the geodesic $l$ is linear in $t$. But one may take a piecewise geodesic path, starting as a geodesic in the hyperbolic plane $x=0$ connecting $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,t,0)$, and then a geodesic in the hyperbolic plane $y=t$ connecting $(0,t,0)$ and $(t,t,0)$. Since the path $(0,u,0), 0\leq u\leq t$ is a horocycle in the hyperbolic plane $x=0$, and similarly $(u,t,0),0\leq u\leq t$ is a horocycle in the hyperbolic plane $y=t$, 
the length of this piecewise geodesic path is on the order of $C\log(t)$. Since the metric space is complete, there is a minimal length geodesic connecting $(0,0,0)$ and $(t,t,0)$ which is not invariant under $\varphi$, and thus there are at least two minimal length geodesic paths (and at least three geodesics) connecting the two points.

Answer (score 7):

Despite their non-uniqueness, a lot is known about geodesics of left-invariant metrics on Heisenberg groups. For example, Jang-Park [[Conjugate points on 2-step nilpotent groups](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1005154817324), Geom. Dedicata 79 (2000), no. 1, 65--80] describe conjugate points for all geodesic passing through the identity element of a simply-connected 2-step nilpotent Lie group with 1-dimensional center. Earlier Kaplan and [Eberlein](https://eudml.org/doc/82371) obtained explicit equations for geodesics (see references in the above paper).

Answer (score 3):

The geodesics in SOL that are not contained in a vertical (hyperbolic) foliation tend to come in families meeting periodically and are thus highly non unique. They are precisely described in my paper *[L’Horizon de SOL](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/114945).*  Expos. Maths 1998.
In this paper, the SOL geodesics are explicitly parametrized using elliptic functions.

Comment: And the geodesics in Nil (= 3D Heisenberg group) are explicitly computed in the book by Gallot-Hulin-Lafontaine (this is exercice 2.90 bis question c in the second edition) the solution is at the end of the book.